# SQL Server : Invalid column name when execute it as SQL command declared variable

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL command that executes well, but when I put it inside a SQL command declared variable it shows an error

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 103
>   Invalid column name 'BusStopName'

Here is the SQL command:

```
SET @sqlCommand2 = 'SELECT TOP (1) [BusStopName], [' +@StationName+ ']
                    FROM ' + @R_tb_nm_temp + ' 
                    WHERE [' +@StationName+ '] >= CONVERT(time(0),''' + CAST(@CurrentTime AS VARCHAR) + ''')';
```

Comment: Please post the resulting SQL (print @sqlCommand2). Maybe you have the wrong table name in @R_tb_nm_temp.

Comment: Odd question: why would you be comparing a station name to a time?

Comment: To escape dynamic identifiers, use `QUOTENAME()` rather than adding brackets yourself. [Do not use `VARCHAR` without specifying a length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). In this case it defaults to `VARCHAR(30)`, which happens to work, but then you may as well be explicit about it. `@R_tb_nm_temp` is a needlessly cryptic name for a variable -- are you suffering under a tyrant king who imposed a vowel tax? Double-check that comparing a column in a variable named `@StationName` to a `TIME` value is meaningful.

Comment: Verify that the value of @R_tb_nm_temp exactly matches the name of the table that contains BusStopName.  You should try Selecting/Printing your sql variable to see what the generated output is.

Comment: Have you printed your @sqlCommand and run it? FYI your table design is going to cause you many issues. The first one being that you need to write buggy insecure dynamic SQL to get anything out of it

Comment: check your table `@R_tb_nm_temp` does it contains a column `[BusStopName]` ?

Comment: Thank u all, specially @jeroen Monster . I the column name [BusStopName] was avalible in some tables and other was not. So, I rename all the columns to be [BusStopName]  name.